# Ubuntu 20.04 won't wake from suspend or completely shutdown

Tags: 20.04, suspend, lenovo, shutdown

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on an Acer Thinkpad A475. Suspend and shutdown have stopped working properly. When I suspend, the laptop won't wake, forcing me to hold the power button until it turns off, then start it up again. When I try to shutdown or restart, the same problem happens. The screen goes black, but the power button remains lit and I have to hold the power button to make the laptop turn off.

I've been googling this problem for several days. One suggestion to diagnose the problem was to power down the laptop, wait a half hour, then forcefully power down by holding the power button, then after restarting, run `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`. This is the result:

```
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Unmounting /run/snapd/ns...
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: run-snapd-ns.mount: Succeeded.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/snapd/ns.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_X76S115GTR4T-part5...
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Succeeded.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-nvme\x2dTHNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_X76S115GTR4T\x2dpart5.swap: Succeeded.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-THNSF5512GPUK_TOSHIBA_X76S115GTR4T-part5.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-6ae277d0\x2d05.swap: Succeeded.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-partuuid/6ae277d0-05.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2did-nvme\x2deui.00080d020033412c\x2dpart5.swap: Succeeded.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-eui.00080d020033412c-part5.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:04:00.0\x2dnvme\x2d1\x2dpart5.swap: Succeeded.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:04:00.0-nvme-1-part5.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: dev-nvme0n1p5.swap: Succeeded.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/nvme0n1p5.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-f1b5903f\x2d71c6\x2d44ba\x2da496\x2d89d18f080500.swap: Succeeded.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/f1b5903f-71c6-44ba-a496-89d18f080500.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: systemd-reboot.service: Succeeded.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Finished Reboot.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Reached target Reboot.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Dec 30 09:53:24 schwartz-lenovo systemd-journald[276]: Journal stopped
```

I've tried looking for missing drivers, with `ubuntu-drivers devices`, but the result is blank. I've seen that this could be also be a GPU or kernel issue. Any help you can provide in finding a solution would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Shutdown and Restart both work when booted into recovery mode, and suspend is closer to working. When booting into recovery mode I get a warning saying "some graphic drivers require a full graphical boot and so will fail when resuming from recover", so maybe this is a graphics driver problem? I've made sure my graphics driver is up to date. My graphics card is an AMD Radeon R7 Graphics and the driver is AMD GPU.

Comment: but did you try to boot with an older kernel?

Comment: The only kernels i have installed are 5.11.0-43-generic and 5.11.0-41-generic. I've tried booting with both of them, and the problem persists

Comment: Any concerns with -oem kernel downgrades?  It's unclear what exists actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this (after trying lots of different fixes and progressively making this worse) by getting a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and choosing to use kernel 5.11.0-27-generic (which came with the install) instead of the newer 5.11.0-43-generic that is the default at the time of writing. So maybe it was a kernel problem all along and I just needed to try an older version (I only tried as old as 5.11.0-38), or maybe there was some other lingering issue as well that the fresh install wiped out.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop and the exact same problem. Been trying to figure it out for the past week. Same results in shutdown logs. Spent some time chasing various errors in the logs (cpufreq, Disk unmount errors, LUKS, fsck, etc), but didn't make a difference. I was able to revert back to kernel 5.11.0.38-generic and everything was back to normal. That version had already rolled out of grub so I added it back here.

```bsh
export KERN_VERSION=5.11.0-38-generic
sudo apt install linux-headers-$KERN_VERSION linux-image-$KERN_VERSION linux-modules-$KERN_VERSION linux-modules-extra-$KERN_VERSION
```

I then marked this one as a keep

```bsh
sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic # I think this will prevent it from auto removing
```

Then turned on grub to remember the last booted kernel. There are probably other better ways too

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub

# Add these settings
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

Now, unsure what is actually wrong with the 41 and 43. Hoping maybe fixed in a later version. Wasn't able to capture an actual error that would point to where to even submit a bug report.